# CSS styles and <ul> <li> tags been ignored while parsing using Apache Tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

While I am parsing the PDF or Word document using AutoDetectParser the "li", "ul" tags are converted as "p" tags. I need the exact HTML content what is been there for PDF or Word Document.

I tried in several ways as below:

```
ToHTMLContentHandler textHandler = new ToHTMLContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
context.set(HtmlMapper.class, new IdentityHtmlMapper());
parser.parse(in, textHandler, metadata, context);
```

---

```
SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
handler.setResult(new StreamResult(writer));
System.out.println(handler.toString());
return handler;
```

But the "li" tags are been replaced with "p" tags with class but the CSS style is not seen in the parsed HTML output.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the exact same problem. Just wondering if you have find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this problem too not sure if we have to convert it to some other format as a workaround before parsing to HTML as a workaround, I will play with it and if I find a solution I will update this.